# How to set multiple duplicate items in Python resource allocation problem, using binpacking module?

Tags: python

I have currently being solving a resource allocation problem, which is called "Bin packing problem", applied for steel manufacturing.
I have a number tube parts of distinct length. They are:
45 parts of 450 mm length

34 parts of 700 mm length

27 parts of 290 mm length

14 parts of 1100 mm length

11 parts of 250 mm length

60 parts of 115 mm length.

I want to set this parts on 3 meter raw tubes such way that can allow to minimize the number of tubes being bought.

I have found further algorithm in google, but it contanes a few number of items, thus there is no example of application algorithm to a greater size of problems.
This algorithm looks like

```
 numberOfBins = 6
 resources = {
    "A" : 5, "B" : 5, "C" : 3, "D" : 4, 
    "E" : 4, "F" : 1, "G" : 4, "H" : 5, 
    "I" : 4, "L" : 3, "M" : 3, "N" : 4,
    "O" : 3, "P" : 2, "Q" : 3, "R" : 1,
    "S" : 5, "T" : 2, "U" : 5, "V" : 3,
    "Z" : 1,
    }
```

So how can I set a multiple duplicate items into such list?
Thank you!

Comment: You should provide the algorithm you found, explain how it failed, and give the expected output matching your example input

Comment: That's not an algorithm.

Comment: If you allow me I will paraphrase: how can I add a numbers of this items into the code?